# Azure Virtual Machine and Web api: how set endpoint

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed a web api project on iis on a virtual machine on azure.

From azure, i have setup an endpoint TCP on the port 47853 and in IIS on the remote machine i have bind the website on port 47853.

Now if in localhost i try the call:

```
http://localhost:47853/Token
```

the API works.

Now i try the same call from remote:

http://ip_address_remote_machine:47853/Token

and i get a 502 error.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an endpoint for the virtual machine, you'll need to ensure that the firewall of the virtual machine also allows the traffic for the protocol and private port corresponding to the endpoint configuration. By default its opened for remote desktop and ssh.